# how to avoid memory leak with alamofire get request?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, alamofire

I have the following code that makes a get request to Google Places API Web Service. The function is declared within another static function in a public struct containing functions of similar nature.

```
private static func GSearchRequest(_ url: URLConvertible,
                                   parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                                   parser: @escaping (Array<[String:NSObject]>?) -> Void)
{
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.response-queue",
                              qos: .utility, attributes: [.concurrent])
    Alamofire.request(url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON(queue: queue, completionHandler: {
            response in
            print(response)
        })
}
```

Below is the function where the above is called

```
static func GSearh(_ query: String, location: CLLocation?,
                   parser: @escaping (Array<[String:NSObject]>?)->Void,
                   host: UIViewController?) {
    if let current_vc = host {
        if !Reachability.isConnected() {
            current_vc.view.offlineViewAppear()
        }
    }
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    if let manager: CLLocation = location {
        coordinate = manager.coordinate
        if let coords = coordinate {
            if let apiKey = appDelegate?.getApiKey() {
                let latitude = coords.latitude
                let longitude = coords.longitude
                let params: Parameters =
                    ["location":"\(latitude),\(longitude)",
                        "rankby":"distance", "type":"\(query)",
                        "key":"\(apiKey)"]
                GSearchRequest(URL, parameters: params,
                               parser: parser)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still learning swift and I am aware strong references can be captured within closures. The problem I am facing is a memory leak caused by the response returned from Alamofire request. I have used the leaks instrument to find that the leaked objects are _NativeDictionaryStorageOwner and _NativeDictionaryStorageImpl. Once the memory that was malloced is released, several calls to release are made for an object that possibly no longer exists. I have no clue how to fix this, and I have looked for alternatives but those alternatives cause more leaks. Can someone please explain what exactly is going on? How do I fix this memory leak?

Comment: What calls `GSearh` (or should it be `GSearch`?).  It's important to know what the `parser` parameter looks like. Closures are a common place where retain cycles (and leaks) are created.

Comment: From the code above, it doesn't look like it will leak, can you post your parser? Side note: it's not good practice to manipulate UI in code that is handling web services call.

Comment: @Jerry, the parser maps the result to an array, but the leak is caused by the response received. I have scrapped most of the code away, and even when I remove the parser completely I still get the leak

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be pretty hard to diagnose the leak from just this bit of code, but a great new tool for finding the cause of memory leaks and retain cycles is the "Debug Memory Graph" tool.  While your application is running, click this button and it will show you all the objects in memory and what has references to them.